# Using Static Methods with Event Handlers

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I've inherited a C# (.NET 2.0) app that has a bunch of static methods. I need to turn one of these methods into an asynchronous event-based method. When the method is complete, I want to fire off an event-handler. My question is, can I fire off an event handler from a static method? If so, how?

When I google, I only find IAsyncResult examples. However, I want to be able to do something like the following:

```
EventHandler myEvent_Completed;
public void DoStuffAsync()
{
  // Asynchrously do stuff that may take a while
  if (myEvent_Completed != null)
    myEvent_Completed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is `DoStuffAsync` static? If not, where is the static method you are referring to?

Answer (score 6):

The process is exactly the same, the only difference is there isn't really a `this` reference.

```
static EventHandler myEvent_Completed;

public void DoStuffAsync()
{
    FireEvent();
} 

private static void FireEvent()
{
    EventHandler handler = myEvent_Completed;

    if (handler != null)
        handler(null, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if the event needed to be instance based right?

Comment: @Michael The question was to do about static events.

Comment: There is a pretty good chance that the static method is a utility method, but the event needs fired on a specific instance. I suppose that's a guess at best, but that's how I interpreted the need of the `DoStuffAsync` event.

Comment: @Lloyd Thread safety. If another thread unsubscribes from the event after the if statement, but before the event is fired, you'll get a NullReferenceException. By making a local copy, the copy doesn't get changed by the other thread unsubscribing, and the null check is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Provided `DoStuffAsync` is static (which it wasn't in your code), the event `myEvent_Completed` would also need to be made static:

```
static EventHandler myEvent_Completed; // Event handler for all instances

public static void DoStuffAsync()
{
  // Asynchrously do stuff that may take a while
  if (myEvent_Completed != null)
    myEvent_Completed(null, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Otherwise, `DoStuffAsync` would need to take an instance of your class to fire the event on:

```
EventHandler myEvent_Completed; // Note: Can still be private

public static void DoStuffAsync(YourClass instance)
{
   // Asynchrously do stuff that may take a while
   if(instance.myEvent_Completed != null)
      instance.myEvent_Completed(instance, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

If you needed different instances of your class to have different event handlers for this event, you'd want to go with the latter route and pass in an instance.

Other than that, there's absolutely nothing wrong with firing an event from a static method.

Comment: You can't use this in a static method.

Comment: @Orch - Oops!  Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

If the `event` is declared in the type you're operating in you can pass in an instance (or recover it if it's a Singleton) and access the `event` object from there. So, for example:

```
EventHandler myEvent_Completed;
public void DoStuffAsync(MyClass o)
{
    // Asynchrously do stuff that may take a while
    if (o.myEvent_Completed != null)
        o.myEvent_Completed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

If it were a singleton you could then do something like this:

```
EventHandler myEvent_Completed;
public void DoStuffAsync(MyClass o)
{
    // Asynchrously do stuff that may take a while
    if (Instance.myEvent_Completed != null)
        Instance.myEvent_Completed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

where `Instance` is the Singleton accessor.